# How do I iterate through an ansible registered value?

Tags: python, json, ansible

So, I had to run a command in `ansible` which will have multiple answers,
 *for example* : Run a command to list the names and other details of all the users. Result will have say,

```
Carry   2/10

Barry   19/7

Harry   7/7

Jerry   11/4

Terry   7/12

Marie   13/10
```

I've saved this result to variable called names in the tasks of the playbook

```
 register: names
```

- How do I iterate through each of these names one at a time and run specific commands when I'm iterating through them?
- Will I have to convert this string to a json file as ansible accepts json?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to run the same command using the different inputs you have for the list variable you created with **register**, you can itterate using with_items:

```
- name: doing something cool
    cmd: my_awesome_cmd {{ item }}
  with_items:
    names
```

You can take a look at the docs here.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/plugins/lookup/items.html

If you want to do different stuff for each input, you can also rely on the fact that you can use register as a list:

```
- name: doing something cool with carry
    cmd: my_awesome_cmd {{ names[0] }}
- name: doing something cool with barry
    cmd: my_awesome_cmd {{ names[1] }}
- name: doing something cool with harry
    cmd: my_awesome_cmd {{ names[2] }}
...
```

You can always use **debug** to print out the output of your variable, that way you can have a better look at the structure and grab exactelly what you're looking for.
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/debug_module.html

Comment: Hi, if I want to use the other column of 'names' registered value? The numbers in the question. I tried using the logic we use while naming elements in matrices, but it didn't work. Any ideas on this?

Comment: I'd have to see the output of your variable, could you try and post it here? Using the debug feature I suggested.

Comment: I managed to figure it out! The output of the variable is a string and I tried to split it wrt spaces like we do in python using split(' ') function and now I can iterate. I used a combination of the two answers I received on this question                                                                                                 - debug: msg="{{(names.stdout_lines[3].split()[3])}}"                            Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate throgh those lines with: `with_lines: "{{ names }}"`

That way each time the `{{ item }}` var gets a line, on which you can run anything you like (for start i would check if the line isn't empty).
I would also recommand to look at [ansible regex filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters) so you could manipulate those strings.

You could also use `with_items: "{{ names.stdout_lines }}"` as the [ansible-documantation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-the-results-of-a-program-execution) says